# How to do a proper search and filter with sequelize node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So I'm trying to create a search and filter function on my app.
In the front and you can:

- Type a search bar to search a product by it's name (with params "nama" in the controller)
- Select categories to filter products by their types (with params "type" in the controller)

**Here's my controller code in the backend**

```
static async show(req, res) {
    let { nama, type } = req.params;

    if (!nama) {
      nama = "";
    }
    if (!type) {
      type = "";
    }
    try {
      let car = await Car.findAll({
        order: [["id", "ASC"]],
        include: [
          {
            model: CarsImage,
            where: { primary: true },
          },
        ],
        where: {
          [Op.and]: [
            {
              nama: {
                [Op.iLike]: "%" + nama + "%",
              },
            },
            {
              type: {
                [Op.iLike]: "%" + type + "%",
              },
            },
          ],
        }
      });

      res.status(200).json(car);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err.message);
    }
  }
```

Here are the problems:

1. Search function alone

- The search function kind of works, but it shows 0 result if I type more than 2 characters. Also it doesn't work when I try to search certain products (I have no clue why it's like that).

2 Search function with filter by type

- It kind works, but when I clear the typeInput state (to clear the filter) in the front end (I'm using react), it stopped functioning properly (it won't reset the result so the result will be empty, unless I clear the search bar, but after that the search function stopped working completely and only the filter works).

3. Filter by type alone

- I works with no problem whatsoever, even after clearing the typeInput state.

I know the reason why I have problem 2 is because it still filters that empty character (after clearing the typeInput state) with the type column in my database, but I can't think of a better logic to do this properly.

Any suggestions or a completely new logic is appreciated! Also let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I set up my route wrong. And after correcting it and adding some adjustment in the front-end, everything works properly

My previous route:

```
router.get("/:type?/:nama?", CarController.show);
```

Corrected route:

```
router.get("/type/:type?/nama/:nama?", CarController.show);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = await User.findAll({
  order: ["first_name"],
  where: {
    [Op.and]: [{ is_enable: true }],
    [Op.or]: [
      {
        first_name: {
          [Op.like]: "%" + serch + "%",
        },
        email: {
          [Op.like]: "%" + serch + "%",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: UserRole,
      attributes: ["user_role", ["id", "RoleID"]],
    },
  ],
  offset: (page - 1) * limit,
  limit: limit,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code has `[Op.and],` what you are trying to achieve is a full-text search,

```
`name = ford, type = fcar`
example case1: when you search f ur search will return result because f is in both name and type, simplifying this true  && true  = true
example case2: when you type c it will not because character c is not present in name but present in type, simplifying this false && true  = false
```

The current code in question returns data if both name, type have same characters

try using [Op.or] which makes more sense while searching for many values

Comment: I get what you meant, but filter by category is in a different input field than search. I also tried [Op.or] but the filter won't work and it returned all result instead

Comment: Aha, then find all by category and then search the name

Comment: it turns out I set up my route wrong and after I corrected it without changing my controller it works correctly. thanks for trying to help anyway!